# Jython save state of program

Tags: java, python, jython

Is it possible to save the state of a Jython program? I want to be able to save all defined variables and the current line the program is on, restart the whole thing, and resume from there. I looked into `Pickling`, but that only serializes a Class, not the entire state. I think what I need is `Continuation` like in stackless Python. Can I do that in Jython?

My Python file looks like this:

```
def main()
    engine.blockingMethod()
    testVar = engine.blockingMethodReturn()
    if(testVar == "a"):
        methodA()
    else:
        methodB()
def methodA ()
    engine.blockingMethod()
def methodB()
    engine.blockingMethod()
```

My program needs to be able to exit after any of these methods. I cannot just read all of them when I load the file, because of the `if` statement. I don't know how to act accordingly, because when the user wants to exit, my program didn't run fully. I run it like this:

```
pyScript.start();
System.out.println("Done")
```

In a separate Thread, because most is the methods I call from my Python file are blocking. I can save previous actions, and run the file until I reach the last one of the saved history, but this wouldn't work because of the `if` statements.  So when the player presses the Exit button, I need to save the state and kill the Thread. Something like this: https://www.renpy.org/doc/html/save_load_rollback.html

Comment: Threading certainly causes summer difficulties. Still, I do not understand your most recent edit. It will help if you can reproduce the problem in a small code example. You do not need to show your entire game. Just created a new program which emulates the parts you are asking about.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I added a link to the documentation of an engine that does saving like I want to do it

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I'm on my phone, but I'll try to throw something together

Comment: I suggest that you build an engine for a specific game. Do not worry yet about making it general-purpose. This will help you gain some programming experience so that you will be able to more easily build a general purpose game engine in the future.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I'm experienced in Java, but not in Jython and Python. Here's the program I made that does what my engine would do: http://pastebin.com/87TdNhWy

Comment: I think you need to learn about event handling. I suggest using a UI library. In Java, you can use Swing. In Python, tkinter is popular.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice What about it? In my Java code I already made InputListeners, KeyboardListeners, ButtonClickListeners and so on.

Comment: why do you create a thread then? In Java, the event queue is already on its own thread.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I create a new Thread, because my methods are blocking, and blocking the GL render thread wouldn't be so useful

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Also, this game needs to run on Android as well, so I can't use AWT classes

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly save the values of variables. That is the whole purpose of a file.

You cannot easily save which line of code you are on. The program should exit at a known point in execution so that it automatically knows how to continue when you restart.

Comment: I need to be able to exit at any point in time. I updated my question

Comment: @LórántViktorGerber your program exits when main() ends. This is clearly defined and not "any instant in time".

Comment: @Code-Apprenrice This is for a game. When the game starts, I call main. When main ends the game also ends. But the player needs to have the ability to click an exit button any time, save and continue later

Comment: @LórántViktorGerber still exiting is at a clearly defined point in your code: the event handler for the button. In that method store all necessary state in a file. When the program starts later, load the state and act accordingly. You do not need to save the current line of code that the program ends on because you already know which line that is: the end of main() or some other well defined exit point.

Comment: @LórántViktorGerber Note that I am assuming there is no catastrophic failure since such an exit means there are other problems to deal with.

Comment: I added some more information on why I don't know how to act accordingly

Answer (score 0):

There was probably an easier method, but I ended up making my own Python parser